# Multiple Buttons of Toolbar in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, toolbar

i need to intimate the user that toolbar contains the scroll bar and there is some more buttons in the toolbar.
Any sample code for the issue.

thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: @steve., in toolbar there are five buttons but in mobile the screen length is small for we are using the scroll bar in the toolbar. so i need to intimate the user tat toolbar contains some more buttons and its hided and u can scroll to view the buttons. thanks steve....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this (in Sencha Touch 2):

```
var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
     id: 'meetingList',
     flex: 1,
     scrollable: {direction: 'horizontal', indicators: false},
     defaults: {width: 200},
     items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Button1'
     },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Button2'
     },
     ....
    ]
});
```